# How to add caption to Imagick polaroidImage?

Tags: php, imagick

[image]

I can create a polaroid effect with imagick using this code:

```
$userphoto->polaroidImage(new ImagickDraw(), $angle);
```

I'd like to add also a caption, but I found no way to to this without using `annotateimage`.

The closest I got was using:

```
$im->newPseudoImage(300, 300, "caption:Put your text");
```

If I add the polaroid effect to it I get what I need, except that I found no way to put the image inside!

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Using imagemagick is so simple as this:

> convert -caption "Faerie Dragon" dragon.gif -gravity center
>   -background black +polaroid anno_polaroid.png

Comment: How do you expect the caption to look? Why don't you use `annotateimage()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more advanced text drawing capabilities than annotateImage provides the solution is to:

- Create a new ImagickDraw object
- Do all the text drawing you want in there.
- Draw the ImagickDraw over the actual image.

A very basic example is [here](http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/drawImage) though it currently doesn't do text.